# How to read a time format from xls/xlsx by Apache POI 3.9?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a cell with the `1:20` time value `(1:20:00)`. How can I read it by **apache poi 3.9**?
My code is checking two cell types, and when it reads the time value, it goes to the `CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC`, and the `1:20` will be `0`. How could I read the exactly `1:20`? Thank you!

```
switch (cell.getCellType()) {
    case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
        cellValue = String.valueOf((int) (cell.getNumericCellValue()));
        break;
    case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
        cellValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
         break;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it!!

```
switch (cell.getCellType()) {
    case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
        if(DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
            cellValue = new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(cell);
        } else {
            cellValue = String.valueOf((int) (cell.getNumericCellValue()));
        }
        break;
    case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
        cellValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
        break;
}
```

Comment: style.setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("@")).// IF the data is in different formats also .it will treat as String.While displaying it will be any problem.